# 200 Request but no responseText and content length of 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener('load', function (txt) {
  console.log(txt)
}, false);
req.open("get", "/foo.txt", true);
req.send();
```

I feel pretty stupid right now like I'm missing something obvious, but that above is returning 200 and the response has the contents of the file. The server logs show a successful request as well. However, `txt` is showing an XHR object with no responseText and 0 response length. The file is just a text file. I also tried changing it to .json just to see if it'd do something different.

Comment: huh? Thats the req load which is the complete event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: sorry, i have to apologize, i've read over your handler declaration too quickly. pointless answer deleted.

Comment: have you tried the actual syntax (`function reqListener () {  console.log(this.responseText); } /* ... */ oReq.onload = reqListener;` that's supplied in the link in your comment to my deleted answer ?

Comment: That was it! Problem was txt.responseText doesn't exist. It's this.responseText. I'm so used to libraries using the first callback as the data :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed `this.responseText` in my load event listener, not `txt.responseText`.